# C# Generate Canvas Image with Bitmap like Javascript does

Tags: javascript, c#, canvas

I'm trying to make an image like I'm doing it in javascript with BITMAP but I'm having some issues. First the font looks thicker than javascript and positioning it doesn't work well

The Javascript looks like:

```
var el = document.createElement("canvas");
el.width = 32, el.height = 32;
var cnt = el.getContext("2d");
cnt.font = "12pt Arial";
cnt.fillText("Hey", 2, 24);
el.toDataURL();//Data image so u can see the javascript image
```

The C# I made looks like:

```
Bitmap objBmpImage = new Bitmap(32, 32);
Font objFont = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
Graphics objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage);

objGraphics.Clear(Color.Transparent);

Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
objGraphics.DrawString("Hey", objFont, textBrush, 1, 12);//This doesnt position it right I think
objBmpImage.Save("test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);//This image is thicker font
```

So problems I got is

1) Text doesn't position in right place

2) Image font looks Thicker than javascript one

3) Want also to have same data:image url as the javascript in c#

Comment: `objGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;`. Play with `objGraphics.TextContrast` and see the [StringFormat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat.-ctor) class. It's used, among other things, to define the correct position of the text. There's an overload of `DrawString()` that accepts a StringFormat argument. If you don't know what to set, start specifying just `StringFormat.GenericTypographic` (it's a pre-set). You have to dispose of: Font, Graphics Object, Brush,  Bitmap object when you have saved it and you're done with it.

Comment: @Jimi I know about Dispose I'll take a look on those options